# Telegram API: кнопка с заготовленным сообщением для бота

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Имеется канал в telegram, в него добавлен бот со всеми правами администратора. Можно ли сделать так, что при клике на кнопку будет открываться диалог с ботом с заготовленным сообщением. Как будто пользователь уже нажал кнопку start, плюс бот получил какую-то служебную информацию, а нажатой кнопке? Грубо говоря, нужно добавить в кнопу url (на бота), callback_data и начать при этом диалог с ботом. Такое реально? Библиотеки не использую, пишу на чистом php. Заранее всем спасибо.

Comment: Нажать Start пользователь должен обязательно сам. По-другому это не работает и не должно.

Comment: В кнопку start можно передавать параметры (в ссылке), смотрите в эту сторону. Но на кнопку start нажать обязаны, это правило телеграма

Comment: Тогда, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно передать параметр в ссылку, чтобы потом прочитать его? Я передаю url в кпонке https://t.me/бот?параметр=значение
Но при переходе пользователем по этой ссылке и нажатии кнопки start это параметра нигде нет.
Единственное, что приходит в голову - это вместо ссылки на бота с параметром передавать ссылку на какой-то свой сервер, записывать параметры там, а затем редиректить на бота. Но звучит как костыль.

Comment: @ИванГоловачёв Вы не можете передать любой параметр. Он жестко определен Telegram Bot Api - это start. Ссылка выглядит htps://bot_username?start=value Это называется deep-linking

Comment: @CausonQ Спасибо. Можете написать ответом, я его отмечу тогда как решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Telegram API есть команда, которая имеет немного больше возможностей - `/start`. С этой командой можно передать один параметр, ссылка будет иметь следующий вид: `t.me/<bot_username>?start=<parameter>`
При переходе по такой ссылке, бот покажет пользователю кнопку Старт, а при нажатии на нее бот получит /start 
Такая возможность называется [Deep-link](https://core.telegram.org/api/links#bot-links)